# Multiple LAN on SonicWall TZ 215

Tags: networking, local-area-network, sonicwall

I have the sonicwall configured as this

- **X0**, LAN,  192.168.1.1
- **X3**, WAN, 1.2.3.4 (sample ip)
- **X4**, LAN, 192.168.3.1

X0 and X4 are natted to go to Internet, but PC with 192.168.1.10 cannot ping PC with 192.168.3.10.  Why?

In network zones LAN group is trusted and "Auto-generate Access Rules to allow traffic between zones of the same trust level" is checked.

**EDIT:**

In packet monitor the error is this:

```
Drop Code: 40(Enforced firewall rule), Module Id: 25(network), (Ref.Id: _5646_uyHtJcpfngKrRmv) 1:1)
```

Comment: Check with sonicwall's packet monitor to see what happens with the packets.

Comment: What happens if you create an explicit rule to allow ping from the LAN zone to the LAN zone?

Comment: A rule to allow all traffic from LAN to LAN already exists

Answer (score 0):

You need static routes built on X0 to tell it 192.168.3.0/24 exists on X4.  And you need static routes built on X4 to tell it 192.168.1.0/24 exists on X0.